# how to achieve update in a streaming table in Delta Live Tables?

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

I want to reflect insert and update of a table:

```
CREATE OR REFRESH STREAMING LIVE TABLE dlt_stage2_bronze_streaming_students ;
APPLY CHANGES INTO LIVE.dlt_stage2_bronze_streaming_students
FROM stream(dlt_test.stage2_test_students_raw)
KEYS (id) 
    where id >= 0
    SEQUENCE BY
      audit_insert 
STORED AS SCD TYPE 2;
```

I can insert rows but if I update rows in "`dlt_test.stage2_test_students_raw`", the pipeline fails immediately. I know streaming table only supports "`append-only`" resource but the official doc says:

```
The default behavior for INSERT and UPDATE events is to upsert CDC events from the source: update any rows in the target table that match the specified key(s) or insert a new row when a matching record does not exist in the target table.
```

How can I update the source table and get it reflected in target table using CDC?